# fancybox with swipe actions causes annoying screen flash on ipad

Tags: jquery-mobile, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm using fancybox 2.1.1 and jQuery-mobile 1.2. It works great to bind the swipe event to next and prev.

Here is the initialization code (coffeescript):

```
  afterShow: ->
    $(".fancybox-wrap").swiperight  $.fancybox.prev
    $(".fancybox-wrap").swipeleft  $.fancybox.next
```

It works, but the background flashes, and sometimes it seems that the images seems the browser gets totally confused.

When I use the button helper, changing the current image using the buttons does not cause the screen to flash. Only left and right swipes do it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the switch on GPU  accelerator.
Try to add in your css

```
.fancybox-wrap { /* or its container */
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

this will active the GPU accelerator before user event

Comment: I tried this both on the .fancybox-wrap as well as the parent container (body's class). I didn't see any difference. I think it must be some small setting as next/prev buttons. The Other thing that happens is that a bad swipe seems to completely mess up the screen. I can see two images at once (transparent). Closing the fancybox, leaves the overlay showing. Is fancybox the right ui widget for ipad/iphone?

Comment: Sorry I've forgot a comma... can you see now?

Comment: @justingordon I don't have any experience with fancybox on touch system. However I had this problem in a "hand made" gallery system. And the symptoms seems the same: the GPU accelerator switch (from a css property like translate3d) cause a flash background and strange other effects.

Comment: BTW, messing with this: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" /> seems to only make things worse for mobile usage.

Comment: Now, with that set on the body, 3 things happen: 1. No swipes, 2. The page can scroll down to see the background. 3. to activate the next/prev buttons (mouse overs), you have to click twice for one activation. Set on the .fancybox-wrap, nothing new happens. The problem seems related to being able to scroll the background. Note, iphone 5 works perfectly regardless for swipe and doesn't work at all for the next/prev mouseover buttons.

Comment: @justingordon very strange... the fancybox plugin is this? https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/blob/master/source/jquery.fancybox.js